# How to change the font size and color of list items in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have an sample application where i am binding the store data to the list using itemtpl, I have little confusion on how to change the color and size of **first two list items** when i am dynamically binding data to list from store.

This my sample code :

```
Ext.define('Sample.view.SearchResultView', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    requires: [
        'Ext.List',
        'Ext.form.FieldSet',
        'Ext.field.Text',
       'Ext.Toolbar',
       'Ext.TitleBar'
    ],

    alias: "widget.searchresultpage",


    config: {
        scrollable: true,
        items: [

              {
                  xtype: 'list',
                  layout:'fit',
                  height:500,
                  title: 'Search Results',
                  store: 'MySearchStore',
                 itemTpl: '<table><td><tr height=10%>{BlockNo}</tr><tr height=90%><p>{ShortDescription}</p></tr></td></table>'

                                               )
              }
        ]
    },



});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add a `cls` attributes to your list like :

```
cls:'myList'
```

and then add this in your CSS File :

```
.myList .x-list-item:nth-child(1),
.myList .x-list-item:nth-child(2) {
  color: #CCC;
  font-size:14px;
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 5):

you can set font and color in `itemTpl` itself.

```
itemTpl: '<table><td><tr height=10%><font size="12" color="#990000">{BlockNo}</font></tr>           
<tr height=90%><p><font size="8" color="#990000">{ShortDescription}</font></p></tr></td>  
</table>'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,my question was how to change the font color and size of only first two items in the list , not for all the items in the list